# django send_mail [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django

I have a problem via sending my emails from django:

```
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: error
Exception Value:    
[Errno 111] Connection refused
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py in create_connection, line 571
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

views.py

```
...
from django.core.mail import send_mail
...
def testmail(request):
    send_mail('subj2', 'message', 'mymail@gmail.com', ['receiver@gmail.com'])
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

But, when I try to send message from console:

```
python manage.py shell
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('subj2', 'message', 'mymail@gmail.com', ['receiver@gmail.com'])
```

It's working, and I sucessfuly receive my message.

Comment: check your firewall

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have done.

`views.py`

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
...
email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=[mailid])
email.send()
...
```

`settings.py`

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abcd@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

And make sure you have https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps enabled.

Comment: I can confirm this (still) works in 2021. I've used the send_mail function (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#quick-example) instead but it's all the same anyway. Thanks for the tip with the google account.